# Autoload of MongoDbRef in C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have two entities

```
public class FileEntity
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("name")]
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("tags")]
    public List<MongoDBRef> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class TagEntity
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("tagId")]
    public string TagId { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("tagName")]
    public string TagName { get; set; }
}
```

How can I force official Mongo C# driver to autoload MongoDBRef references in property "Tags" of FileEntity when I call Find() method?

Comment: I don't think that's even possible. However, have you seen this? https://chrisbitting.com/2015/03/24/mongodb-linking-records-documents-using-mongodbref/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's deprecated functionality. You should manually retrieve referenced data.